# Is it OK to post a question and self answer it within 1 minute?

Tags: support, self-answer

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Should I ask a question I know the answer to?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to)
>   [Moving a personal technical blog to Stack Overflow/Server Fault](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/moving-a-personal-technical-blog-to-stack-overflow-server-fault)

Is it OK to post a question and self answer it within 1 minute? Does that amount to **gaming the system**?

Here is the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718343/how-to-use-floating-point-tolerances-in-the-catch-framework) I'm referring to.

Comment: No, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I ask a question I know the answer to?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to), [Should I ask questions intended to be self-answered?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97877/should-i-ask-questions-intended-to-be-self-answered)

Comment: The specific sin here is spamming the large [c++] audience with a non C++ jeopardy question.  Corrected.  This isn't addressed in any of the linked questions afaict.  Well, too late.

Comment: Agreed that the C++ tag doesn't belong. I missed that or I'd have edited it myself. But that's not what was asked here. The linked questions *do* answer the question asked in the title. Mistagged questions are another problem altogether, covered in more detail here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98590/attention-grabbing-questioners

Answer (score 5):

My take on this: The question had better be useful to others, otherwise there's no point in posting it here. i.e. Not a "find my parse error" question. The answer had better be spot on too, otherwise it belongs in the question as "This is what I've tried". Otherwise, I do find this a bit odd, but nonetheless helpful. If the user gets votes, he deserves it for sharing something he could have kept to himself.

I don't think the time between posts has any bearing, but if OP was interested in hearing other answers - it would probably be beter to post his solution later, otherwise people will assume it's resolved. However, this could be seen as being "tricky" or wasting people's time.

Sometimes I feel inclined to do this when I can't find the answer on SO, but I've resolved the issue finally after my own efforts and research. I would have been happy to have found the answer here first, so in the spirit of giving - I think it's great to post it as a question+answer. If *I* was looking for this, surely someone else will be too, and now the answer *is* on SO.